# XHTML and CSS books

Tags: css, xhtml

I would like to learn moders XHTML and CSS programming. Does someone has any good book suggestions where to start? I would like to have a book where I can learn those languages completely or as much as possible and I can use them if I get trouble on my web-programming projects. And of course I would like that my sites passes web-standards and validators and teaches what are different DTD's.

Comment: Not really duplicate, but for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362251/what-are-the-best-books-on-html-and-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't waste your money on a book, there are so many good websites that do this:

- [HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/)
- [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)
- [HTML.net](http://www.html.net/tutorials/html/)

All of these websites are free and will help you begin learning web development.

Comment: I have heard that at least W3Schools contains some mistakes.

Comment: @Jaska - Where did you hear this?

Comment: http://keskustelu.suomi24.fi/node/8293380

Translation

w3schools is a cheating page which tries to look as a w3c-site but it is yeasty and contains mistakes. It might be fun to read for those who does not read books.

Comment: +1: Any web development book you buy is going to be outdated in a couple of years anyway.

Comment: @Jaska - Ah I see.  I was more hoping to see some examples as to the exact mistakes that it contains.

Comment: @Andrew - I think I found a mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212705/how-does-css-clearing-really-work

Comment: HTML Dog has a book version too, it is just as good as the web site.

Comment: While there is a lot of good information online, I personally find that sitting down with a systematic, well-edited book is the best way for me to learn new topics, and online tutorials help fill in the gaps as I run into questions.

Comment: +1. HTMLDog is both a very good book and a great website.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [CSS: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527334/) if you want to really understand how CSS works. There's some how-to, but more information on what the rules mean and how things work.

This is how I learned CSS, and it makes a great reference. From there you can understand more of the clever tricks you find online.

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever needed [Dynamic HTML: The Definitive Reference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dynamic-HTML-Definitive-Comprehensive-JavaScript/dp/0596003161). Having a first edition from 1998 means everything it contains is supported almost eniterly in modern browsers. The 2nd edition is still pretty old from 2002 though so that's probably similar.

I also make good use of Peter-Paul Koch's excellent site [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/) which covers browser compatability about as well as I could imagine anyone doing.

Comment: All though these are good books, the question is about XHTML & CSS. Not Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

[Head First HTML with CSS & xHTML](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/) would be a good starter book. I have not read it specifically, but have read others in the Head First series and think they're excellent.

They are specifically for beginners, and use a lot of innovative techniques for helping you understand and remember what you're learning.

Answer (score 1):

[Css Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145) - is the best CSS book I have read.  If you think you know a lot about CSS, this book will open eyes!

Answer (score 1):

I would second the recommendation of [Head First HTML with CSS & xHTML](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/).

Other good "starter" books would be:

- [Designing with Web Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321385551)
- [Bulletproof Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)
- [The Zen of CSS Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321303474)

All of the above are very readable and focused on the practical.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) and the associated book, [The Zen of CSS Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321303474). I'm not sure that's the best way since the books are more about the design aspects of css, but it worked for me.