# HTML - trying to move element to bottom of the page

Tags: html

Below is a screen shot as well as a copy of the HTML from an ASP MVC website. The final paragraph element (at the bottom of the code) is lining up horizontally with the other two fieldsets, however I need it to be at the bottom of the page. HTML/web design has always been an achilles heel of mine, so if someone could explain what is going on and a possible solution I would be more than thankful.

```
@model Monet.Models.FollowUpItems

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Follow Up Item</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">     </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div>
<span style = "float:left;padding-right:4em">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Status Items</legend>

    <div class="error">
        @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</span>
<span style="clear:both;"></span>
<span style="float:left;">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Basic Info</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TableName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TableName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TableName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastUpdateBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastUpdateBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastUpdateBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastUpdateOn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastUpdateOn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastUpdateOn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Key1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Key1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Key1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Key2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Key2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Key2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IssueType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueType)
        </div>
</fieldset>
</span>

</div>
<span style="clear:both;"></span> 
 }
 <span style="clear:both;"></span>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from your code if clearing spans are set to dispaly: block, but I have hunch they should be:

```
<span style="display:block;clear:both;"></span>
```

Comment: Just to be clear - should i add this to the "clear" span tag or replace this: <span style = "float:left;padding-right:4em;"> with what you provided?

Comment: To the ones you intend to use a 'clearing' elements. I usually create a 'clearing style' rule, like .clearFix{ display: block; clear:both; } and use that where necessary

Comment: I put this in both of the <span> "clear" tags and it fixed the problem. Could you explain what is going on? (would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: To be honest, no, not on an 'assembler' level. I've been using it since 'dirt'. Here's a question just on that subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212705/how-does-css-clearing-really-work

Answer (score 0):

#### Span is an `inline` element

Replace this:

```
<span style = "float:left;padding-right:4em">
```

With:

```
<div style = "float:left;padding-right:4em; overflow: hidden;">
```

And yeah, please convert all the `<span>`s to `<div>`s and check.

Comment: Don't forget the closing tag too! </span> -> </div>

Comment: That didn't work. Was the <div> tag you suggested supposed to enclose one <fieldset>, both, or all content?

Comment: @NealR Legally, the `fieldset` should be enclosed inside `form` tags, yeah, all the content.